# Does Gremlin.NET support submitting async bytecode?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gremlin, amazon-neptune

There are extension functions for [submitting queries asynchronously](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/dotnetdocs/3.4.6/api/Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClientExtensions.html) in Gremlin.Net, some get `string` which is [not recommended](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_submitting_scripts_3) and others use [`RequestMessage`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/dotnetdocs/3.4.6/api/Gremlin.Net.Driver.Messages.RequestMessage.html) which is not as readable as using [`GraphTraversal`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/dotnetdocs/3.4.6/api/Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.GraphTraversal-2.html) functions.

Is there a way to submit a query like the one below asynchronously, without submitting a string or `RequestMessage`?

```cs
var res = _graphTraversalSource.V().Has("name", "Armin").Out().Values<string>("name").ToList();
```

#### A little more context

I'm writing an API that queries AWS Neptune. Here's how I get the `GraphTraversalSource` in the constructor of a singleton service (not sure if I should make the `RemoteConnection` a singleton and generate a `GraphTraversalSource` for each query or this is the right approach):

```cs
private readonly GraphTraversalSource _graphTraversalSource;

public NeptuneHandler(string endpoint, int port)
{
    var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer(endpoint, port));
    var remoteConnection = new DriverRemoteConnection(gremlinClient);
    _graphTraversalSource = AnonymousTraversalSource.Traversal().WithRemote(remoteConnection);
}
```

Comment: I am not a .Net expert but the general guidance when working with Gremlin clients and remote connections is to share the traversal source amongst the threads in your application as that will enable the underlying web socket worker pool and connection pool to be shared.

Comment: You already have the right way to execute a Gremlin traversal with Gremlin.NET in your question: `graphTraversalSource.V().Has("name", "Armin").Out().Values<string>("name").ToList();`. What exactly is not working with that?

Comment: @FlorianHockmann that is working just fine, I was looking for a way to `await` on it. I found the answer to that: `await remoteConnection.SubmitAsync(traversal.ByteCode)`, my other question is the thread safety of `DriverRemoteConnection`. Can I share an object of that type among threads?

Comment: The recommended way to execute a traversal asynchronously is actually to append `.Promise()` to it, .e.g.: `g.V(1).Values<string>("name").Promise(t => t.Next());`.
Yes, a `DriverRemoteConnection` should be shared across your application. The usual recommendation in Gremlin is to actually share the traversal source `g`, but that also includes the `DriverRemoteConnection`.

Comment: @FlorianHockmann thanks! Can you post an answer, so I can approve it? Can you also include a reference to the docs where it recommends sharing `g`? I've been looking for that but couldn't find it.

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer. It looks however like the recommendation is nowhere in the TinkerPop docs so I created an issue for that: [TINKERPOP-2354](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2354)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute a traversal asynchronously with the `Promise()` terminator step

```
var names = await g.V().Has("name", "Armin").Out().Values<string>("name").Promise(t => t.ToList());
```

`Promise()` takes a callback as its argument that calls the usual terminator step you want to be executed for your traversal which is `ToList` in your case. If you however only want to get a single result back, then you can just replace `ToList()` with `Next()`.

Note that I renamed the variable for the graph traversal source to `g` as that is the usual naming convention for Gremlin.

As I already mentioned in my comment, it is recommended to reuse this graph traversal source `g` across your application as it can contain configuration that applies to all traversals you want to execute. It also contains the `DriverRemoteConnection` which uses a connection pool for the communication with the server. By reusing `g`, you also use the same connection pool for all traversals in your application.